# Are old WiFi AP settings stored in Ubuntu Server?

Tags: wireless, networking, server, 13.10, network-manager

I have Ubuntu Server 13.10 and I used it earlier to connect to many access points

I used `ifconfig`, `iwconfig` and `/etc/network/interfaces` file to do that

Now, the WiFi adapter is de-associating from the access point of my interest, there are others in range

I was wondering where is the Network Manager or if the old settings for other APs are still stored and the adapter is trying to associate with them based on the highest RSSI

If they are still stored somewhere, how to delete them

Thanks

---

Update 1:

I installed the `network-manager` package

Now, I have this directory `/etc/NetworkManager`

Is it possible to use it to find the stored wifi settings?

---

Update 2:

This is what I use in the `interfaces` file

auto wlan0

iface wlan0 inet manual

wireless-essid ASUS-2.4

wireless-key 1111111111

wireless-mode Managed

Comment: Since you are manually configuring anyway, maybe you want network manager to ignore the card: http://askubuntu.com/questions/21914/how-can-i-make-networkmanager-ignore-my-wireless-card

Comment: @user7134 I don't have the `/etc/NetworkManager` directory in my system

Comment: @user7134 Please read the update

Comment: Are there several networks nearby with the same name, also known as SSID? If so, removing old networks from Network Manager will not help you. It is better to get either NM or /etc/network/interfaces to bind to only your preferred network. Find out with: sudo iwlist wlan0 scan

Comment: @chili555 There are no APs in the area with the same name, I added how I tell Ubuntu to associate with the APs in Update 2. However, an old AP is in range and I don't want my computer to jump between them.

Answer (score 0):

Your `/etc/network/interfaces` file uses the method 'manual' (I think you mean static) but declares no static address and other details. It also implies that your network is encrypted with WEP. WEP is extremely insecure and can usually be cracked in minutes. I strongly recommend you change the encryption in the router to WPA2-AES and then set up `/etc/network/interfaces` like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.150
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8
wpa-essid ASUS-2.4
wpa-psk 222222222222
```

Of course, substitute your details here. Restart the interface:

```
sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup -v wlan0
```

Now is it stable?

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations I'm totally aware of them; I'm using WEP because I don't wanna cause overhead on my slow computer and `manual` because this interface is part of a bonding interface.

Comment: Is there a way to delete the old settings?

Comment: In a server, in which Network Manager is not installed, and for which there are no DHCP leases, I am unaware of any place old settings are stored. I wonder if it is the wireless driver that's dropping.