# Lock Wifi for children

Tags: wireless

I would like to give an ubuntu pc to my children. And since they are quite young (5 and 7) I would like to shut down the Wifi completely for them. However, to update the pc and download applications, I have to activate it from time to time. And then, it remembers the password and connects automatically. Is there a way to either disable the remembering of the wifi-password (I dont want to disable the password-manager completely) or to attach an extra "lock" to it, eg by unmounting/mounting the wifi-adapter with a password?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: what about hidden SSID? not interested?

Comment: `nmcli radio wifi off` startup application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to lock down connecting to a specific WiFi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590923/how-to-lock-down-connecting-to-a-specific-wifi)

Comment: Would it be possible to connect PC by wire once a week or every two weeks for updates?

Comment: You could setup a user ID for your children (no WiFi) and a user ID for yourself (all privileges including WiFi). This could help them from damaging system too if they were non-sudo user.

Comment: Just something to think about, I was fixing(simple fix) my parents hi-fi turntable at that age.

Comment: Thnaks for all the comments! We solved it now as WinEunuchs2Unix suggested and set a second ID for them. In fact, the argument that we can easily repair any damage convinced us most.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iptables` with the owner module , just for their user. The wifi will work for the rest of the system and for all other users. The syntax is:

`iptables -A OUTPUT -o wlan0 -m owner --uid-owner USERNAME -j DROP`

That would drop all output packages to wlan0 for user USERNAME, effectivly killing internet for them.